# Django 2.3 Inside get_absolute_url, Reverse for 'post_detail' not found

Tags: python, django

**Main urls.py includes:**

```
path('', include('page.urls', namespace='page'))
```

**Page app urls.py**

```
app_name = 'page'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='home'),  
    path('page/<slug:slug>/', views.page_detail, name='page_detail'),

]
```

**Page app models.py**

```
    class Page(models.Model):
        .
        .
        .
         def __str__(self):
             return '{} by {} {}'.format(self.title, self.created, self.is_active)

         def get_absolute_url(self):
             return reverse("page_detail", kwargs= {"slug": self.slug })

In page app views.py:

    def home(request):

        pages = Page.objects.filter(is_active=1)

        context = {

            "pages":pages
        }

        return render(request,'page/home.html', context)

    def page_detail(request, slug):

        details = get_object_or_404(Page, slug=slug, is_active='1')

        return render(request,'page/details.html', {'details': details})


In the menu.html under templates/page:

    <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse bs-navbar-collapse navbar-right" role="navigation">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    {% for obj in pages %}
                    <li><a href='{{obj.get_absolute_url}}'>{{ obj.title }}</a></li>
                    {% endfor %}

                </ul>
    </nav>
```

Why am I getting:

> Reverse for 'page_detail' not found. 'page_detail' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

But if I use `<li><a href='/page/{{obj.slug}}'>{{ obj.title }}</a></li> in menu.html` under templates/page it's working properly. The get_absolute_url is not working properly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
         return reverse("page:page_detail", kwargs= {"slug": self.slug })
```

you should add the app name also, when you make a reverse url lookup

Comment: Thanks a lot, but why the other's code work, they are also using the URL name directly, is it related to version or what.

Comment: the proper way to call a url in template is {% url 'appname:your_detail_url' object.slug %} this way, if you are not using get absolute url method